# could not load private key asn.1 decoding failure Navicat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, database, sql, navicat

I have a Problem with my Navicat when i want to connect with a SSh-Key to our Company Servers i cant because Navicat give the folloing Error: could not load private key asn.1 decoding failure

Has anyone an Idea what is going on?